# Почему в этом коде показывает min 0? Объясните пожалуйста

Tags: c#, циклы

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            int[] x = new int[10];
            int sum = 0;
            int max = x[0];
            int min = x[0];
            int i = 0;

            while (i < x.Length)
            {
                x[i] = Random.Shared.Next(100);
                Console.WriteLine($"x[{i}] = {x[i]}");
                sum = sum + x[i];




                if (x[i] > max)
                {
                    max = x[i];
                }
                if  (x[i] < min)
                {
                    min = x[i];
                    
                }
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Sum = {sum}");



            double avg = (double)sum / x.Length;
            Console.WriteLine($"Avarage = {avg}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Max = {max}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Min = {min}");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Произведите дебаг и посмотрите самостоятельно почему что происходит

Comment: сделала, не выдает никакой ошибки

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger

Comment: А почему должно выдавать какую-то ошибку? Существуют ещё **логические** ошибки

Comment: В каком диапазоне выдает значения Random.Shared.Next(100)? Чему равно x[0] на момент инициализации min?